# MySQL error message,error code 1064,LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to join 2 tables. The one contains users and the other appointments-the appointments table contains 3 columns(ApID,which is the primary key),bookFrom,bookedFor-these last 2 columns reference the users table and I think it is easy self_explanatory what they mean.
Here are the tables in detail:

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `user_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hash` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `usertype` enum('1','2','3','4') DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_ID`),
 KEY `fk_users_usertype1_idx` (`usertype`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_users_usertype1` FOREIGN KEY (`usertype`) REFERENCES `usertype` (`type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
 `apID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Bookfrom` int(11) ,
 `bookedfor` int(11) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`apID`),
 KEY `fk_appointments_user1_idx` (`Bookfrom`),
 KEY `bokkedfor` (`bookedfor`),
 CONSTRAINT `appointments_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`bookedfor`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `appointments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Bookfrom`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What I am trying to find  is if a specific user(that user has an email of papageorgiou40@testmail.com) is listed in the appointments table(meaning has booked an appointment) and I am trying to do this with this statement:

```
select  appointments.Bookfrom,appointments.Bookedfor 
from appointments,users 
where users.email='papageorgiou40@test.com' 
and appointments.Bookfrom=users.user_ID,
appointments.Bookedfor=users.user_ID;
```

But I get the following message:

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '
>   appointments.Bookedfor=users.user_ID LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' at line 4

You might wonder why 2 columns bookedfrom and bookedfor. The reason is that in the users table there are 2 types of users, business and regular users, so the logic is a regular user who books an appointment for a business one.I am not sure this the proper db design for the occasion but that is a different discussion

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want an `OR` in there. Or you could do this:

```
... AND users.user_ID IN (appointments.Bookfrom,appointments.Bookedfor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an operator in your where clause:

```
select  appointments.Bookfrom,appointments.Bookedfor 
from appointments,users 
where users.email='papageorgiou40@test.com' 
and appointments.Bookfrom=users.user_ID,
appointments.Bookedfor=users.user_ID;
```

Try this instead:

```
select  appointments.Bookfrom,appointments.Bookedfor 
from appointments,users 
where users.email='papageorgiou40@test.com' 
and (appointments.Bookfrom=users.user_ID
or appointments.Bookedfor=users.user_ID);
```

Comment: There is one more question I would like to make relative to the above query though. The above query returns 2 columns. It searches the user with the email above in 2 columns . It is possible by using the same query(and some php code) to learn EXACTLY in which column(bookfrom or bookedfor) the above user appears? Or do I have to write two queries for such a task?